# uint256(uint160(msg.sender)) and uint256(bytes32(bytes20(msg.sender))) return different results

Tags: byte, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I don't know why uint256(uint160(msg.sender)) and uint256(bytes32(bytes20(msg.sender))) return different results .

```
contract test {
    
     function check1() public  view returns(uint ) {
        return uint256(uint160(msg.sender)) ; 
    }

     function check2() public  view returns(uint ) {
        return uint256(bytes32(bytes20(msg.sender))) ;
    }



}
```

The function check1() returns the value 520786028573371803640530888255888666801131675076 ;
The function check2() returns the value  41260920106969412157321674113669319076297763250177730552014715551905833025536 which is vastly larger than the previous value .

in theory, both check2() and check3() should return the same numerical value representing the msg.sender address because there was no loss of information .
msg.sender is indeed 20 bytes and uint160 .
I don't know where , specifically , that both values become different .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:
`bytes32` pads the `bytes20` object with zeros to the right.

This can be seen by returning the bytes instead of trying to convert them to a uint256.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract Test {
    
     function check1() public  view returns(bytes20) {
        return bytes20(msg.sender) ; 
    }

     function check2() public  view returns(bytes32) {
        return bytes32(bytes20(msg.sender)) ;
    }

}
```

Calling `check1()` gives me: `0x5b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc4`
Calling `check2()` gives me: `0x5b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc4000000000000000000000000`

As for why, I'm not sure if this is because how memory gets read to the stack when returned or if this is something to do with explicit conversion and padding rules. If I figure it out, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The results of check1 and check2 functions in your Solidity code are different because they use different type conversions on the msg.sender address.

Let's break down each function:

### check1:

```
return uint256(uint160(msg.sender));
```

In this function, the msg.sender address is first cast to uint160 (an unsigned integer with a width of 160 bits), and then it is cast to uint256 (an unsigned integer with a width of 256 bits). The result is that the lower 160 bits of the original address are kept, and the upper 96 bits are padded with zeros.

### check2:

```
return uint256(bytes32(bytes20(msg.sender)));
```

In this function, the msg.sender address is first cast to bytes20 (a fixed-size byte array with a length of 20), then it is cast to bytes32 (a fixed-size byte array with a length of 32), and finally, it is cast to uint256. This operation effectively pads the original address with zeros to make it a 256-bit value.

Because of these different type conversions, the resulting values in check1 and check2 will be different even though the `msg.sender` is the same. The specific bit patterns retained and padded with zeros differ between the two conversions.